# How to pull out certain data from returned JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, string

So I have an application in JavaScript that takes a users photo and then sends it off to a face recognition API and it returns a JSON value, Then I have that converted to a string. But I only two of the items that are returned to me are important.I want to pull out those two (uid and confidence) and set them as variables; which I'm not entirely sure how to do. Here's an example of what is returned:

```
{"photos":[{"url":"http://api.skybiometry.com/fc/images/get?id=bmN2X3hybD0wMTk5c29ub3I0MXE0bjN…RyMTQzJmVxPTE1ODkmY3ZxPTY5MjcxMzEyMTI3cTImZ3Z6cmZnbnpjPTIwMTMwNDE0MTgxNjI5","pid":"F@0deeecd9274c7d8357343ed57e6aaf6c_69271312127d2","width":380,"height":300,"tags":[{"tid":"TEMP_F@0deeecd9274c7d8357343ed500c20089_69271312127d2_51.05_45.67_0_1","recognizable":true,"threshold":20,"uids":[{"uid":"sam@sam","confidence":100}],"confirmed":false,"manual":false,"width":20,"height":25.33,"center":{"x":51.05,"y":45.67},"eye_left":{"x":56.32,"y":39.67},"eye_right":{"x":46.32,"y":40},"mouth_center":{"x":48.68,"y":55.67},"nose":{"x":50.79,"y":47},"yaw":0,"roll":1,"pitch":0,"attributes":{"face":{"value":"true","confidence":60}}}]}],"status":"success","usage":{"used":5,"remaining":95,"limit":100,"reset_time_text":"Sun, 14 April 2013 18:20:53 +0000","reset_time":1365963653}}
```

Here is the code I'm currently using right now to return the entire string:

```
.done(function (result) {
    alert("Received response..");
    var resultObject = JSON.stringify(result);
    alert(resultObject);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ have a read

Comment: JSON.parse() not JSON.stringify()

Comment: resultObject['uid'] and resultObject['confidence'] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 .done(function (result) {
     if(result != null) {
        var uids = result.photos[0].tags[0].uids[0]; 
        var uid = uids.uid; 
        var confidence = uids.confidence; 

     } });
```

Comment: The third line should be `var uids = result.photos[0].tags[0].uids[0];`.

Comment: so jsfiddle says I should use !== to compare null, so heres the edited code that I have:  .done(function (result) {
     if(result !== null) {
        var uids = result.photos[0].tags[0].uids[0]; 
        var uid = uids.uid; 
        var confidence = uids.confidence; 
         alert(uid);

     } });

Comment: and it gives an error in console of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uids' of undefined

Comment: @user2266621 That would indicate that the `tags` array in the `result` you are processing is present but empty. Are you sure `tags` is not empty your specific `result`? It works fine with the sample data you posted in this question.